# Creating function in python - while loop won't end

Tags: python, python-3.x

So here is the code I have:

def userInputInt(LL, UL):

```
"""Asks for user input for an integer value within a certain limit"""
need_input = True
while need_input == True:
    print("Please enter an integer between ",LL," and ",UL, ": ", sep='')
    user = input()
    if user >= 'LL' and user <= 'UL':
         need_input == False
         return int(user)
```

I wanted to be able to accept anything in the input and still have it work. But my while loop keeps going regardless of what I put in, even if it is within the parameters.

Any suggestions?

---

Thanks for all the help!

I wanted to compare them as strings so a user could input letters and not have it crash. But I forgot putting ' ' makes the variable literal.

My solution:

```
while need_input == True:
    print("Please enter an integer between ",LL," and ",UL, ": ", sep='')
    user = input()
    if user >= str(LL) and user <= str(UL):
         need_input = False
```

Comment: You are comparing `user` to the strings `'LL'` and `'UL'`, not the values of `LL` and `UL` passed into your function. And `need_input == False` should be `need_input = False`

Comment: I figured as user is also a str it should compare them once they are all numbers. Like making r = '1' then asking if r is greater than '0'. I tried a test of that and it seemed to work.

Comment: Yes, you should compare them as numbers.  Instead, you're comparing them both as strings!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second what @Wondercricket said. User is not actually a string, it is a variable that is equal to a string or integer (whatever your case may be). When you put quotes around LL and UL you treat them as the literal strings 'LL' and 'UL' rather than the values that they are equal to. You need to treat them as the variable LL and UL so that the values of LL and UL can be compared to the value of the user variable.

Edited to address handling for users entering something other than integers. Include a try except in order to try to cast the input to an integer. If it is not possible because the user did not enter an integer, ask for the input again by placing the continue keyword in the except clause. Once an input that can be cast to an integer is entered, the code will move to the line that is checking whether the int is between LL and UL:

```
LL = 10
UL = 20
need_input = True
while need_input == True:
    print("Please enter an integer between ",LL," and ",UL, ": ", sep='')
    try:
        user = int(input())
    except:
        continue
    if user >= LL and user <= UL:
        need_input = False
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that. I wasn't thinking of them as literal.  Though, It still leaves me with the problem of checking a user. It will fail if they plug in a letter or symbol.

Comment: I'm still learning python and have not yet covered try/except. But already I see so many options for it. Thank you for showing me something new!!